Can't compile Arduino ESP32 code: .../python3: exec format error
Yesterday I had no problem compiling Arduino sketches using either the MacOS Arduino IDE or VS Code.
But today nothing compiles. Any sketch that I try to compile in the Arduino IDE or VS Code with Arduino Extension gives this error:
fork/exec /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3: exec format error
Compilation error: fork/exec /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3: exec format error

It looks to me like a Python issue, but I'm lost on how to diagnose it.
I'm including the following in case it may be helpful:
When I run:   "~ which python3"  I get:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3

When I run: "~ python --version" I get:
Python 3.10.6

...and the only thing I can think of that I did that might have changed things was I ran the MacOS "Docker" app to check it out and quit it soon after opening. Could that have done something to my Python installation?
Would much appreciate any help. Thanks...
The compilation error:
    Creating esp32 image...
Merged 27 ELF sections
Successfully created esp32 image.
Multiple libraries were found for "PubSubClient.h"
  Used: /Users/(username)/Documents/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient
  Not used: /Users/(username)/Documents/Arduino/libraries/TBPubSubClient
Multiple libraries were found for "WiFi.h"
  Used: /Users/(username)/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.17/libraries/WiFi
  Not used: /Users/(username)/Documents/Arduino/libraries/WiFiNINA
python3 /Users/(username)/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.17/tools/gen_esp32part.py -q /private/var/folders/7f/4qj_xs8117z4jzt1k609bcc40000gp/T/arduino/sketches/E3FEF3521140621E6A9B6D076EFE409D/partitions.csv /private/var/folders/7f/4qj_xs8117z4jzt1k609bcc40000gp/T/arduino/sketches/E3FEF3521140621E6A9B6D076EFE409D/Async_OTA_DRD_MQTT_1.ino.partitions.bin
Using library AsyncElegantOTA at version 2.2.8 in folder: /Users/(username)/Documents/Arduino/libraries/AsyncElegantOTA 
Using library WiFi at version 2.0.0 in folder: /Users/(username)/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.17/libraries/WiFi 
Using library AsyncTCP at version 1.1.4 in folder: /Users/(username)/Documents/Arduino/libraries/AsyncTCP 
Using library Update at version 2.0.0 in folder: /Users/(username)/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.17/libraries/Update 
Using library ESP Async WebServer at version 3.0.6 in folder: /Users/(username)/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ESP_Async_WebServer 
Using library FS at version 2.0.0 in folder: /Users/(username)/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.17/libraries/FS 
Using library PubSubClient at version 2.8 in folder: /Users/(username)/Documents/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient 
Using library ESPAsync_WiFiManager at version 1.15.1 in folder: /Users/(username)/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ESPAsync_WiFiManager 
Using library ESP AsyncDNSServer at version 1.0.0 in folder: /Users/(username)/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ESPAsyncDNSServer 
Using library ESP32 Async UDP at version 2.0.0 in folder: /Users/(username)/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.17/libraries/AsyncUDP 
fork/exec /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3: exec format error

Compilation error: fork/exec /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3: exec format error


I did a thorough uninstall of all Python installations (except the macOS system version, which macOS requires).
That didn't work, so I manually deleted all remaining Python directories (both Python2 and Python3), frameworks, anything I could find. Then I used "brew doctor" and "brew cleanup" to point out broken links and other issues.
This fixed the issue, although some other apps that required Python now had issues. Those were all resolved by re-installing Python with brew install python3. All seems good now.
